# Python 3: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, typeerror

My program contains this

```
print("hyy")
print(self.reward, self.gamma, max_val)
print(self.reward + (self.gamma * max_val))
```

Here `self.reward` is -0.25, `self.gamma` is 1 and `max_val` is 0.

When I run the code my output is:

```
hyy
-0.25 1 0.0
    ans = goal.value_iteration()
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/MDP-master/value.py", line 237, in value_iteration
    print(self.reward + (self.gamma * max_val))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

The first two lines compile successfully. Why not the third line of my code block? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.gamma` is not numeric. Most likley, it's a string. Here's a minimal example which reproduces your error:

```
a, b, c = -0.25, '1', 0.0

a + b * c  # TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Multiplying a string by an integer is defined, e.g. `'a' * 2 == 'aa'`, but multiplying a string by a float such as `0.0` is not. To convert to numeric you can use `float`:

```
a + float(b) * c  # -0.25
```

Answer (score 0):

Are You sure, that all variables are correct type?
Try using 
`print(type(value))`

to determinate this fact. You can always use casting float(variable)